# Wikipedia Command Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```py
@commands.command()
@commands.cooldown(1,10,BucketType.user)
async def wiki(self,ctx,*,word):
    def sum(arg):
        definition = wikipedia.summary(arg,sentences=3,chars=1000)
        return sum(word)
    await ctx.send(sum)
```

I am making a Wiki command, it doesn't work as expected and responds with this:

[image: Bot Response]

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are using `sum` the wrong way. Instead of this:

```py
await ctx.send(sum)
```

you have to do this:

```py
await ctx.send(sum(word))
```

Also, why are you invoking the function from within itself? In `sum` you should return `definition`.

Try not to shadow the builtin `sum`. You should rename the function to be `get_definition` or something else instead.